# how can i get the the attribute label from the attribute value in magento 2?

Tags: attributes, product, magento2

I got the attribute value 232 from the below code

```
$_product->getData('farben');
```

How I get its label from this value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try this code

Step 1)First you have to load the products

```
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

Step 2)In the product listing page ,there will be a foreach loop for listing the products like this

```
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product)
```

Step3)Your code will be inside this loop.Place the below code at a place whereever you want to display the attribute label.

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('your_attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Just replace **your_attribute_code** with whatever your attribute is named.

Comment: @Divya actually this code is used to get custom attribute values not label.If you have any idea please give related answer

Comment: $_product->getResource() its a deprecated functionality and should not be used

Answer (score 9):

Try with

```
$_product->getAttributeText('farben');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php if (null !== $_product->getCustomAttribute('attribute_code')): ?>
    <?= $_product->getAttributeText('attribute_code'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You should maybe explain the code, so OP understands the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
$passing_marks = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code');

$passing_marks->getFrontend()->getLabel($_product);
```